# Embed pseudo element in class with &

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm building a knob with CSS/JS and I stumbled on a CSS syntax in an example that I wanted to reproduce in my code, but it does not seem to work. I also tried to force different `z-index` but without success.

This is working:

```
.knob 
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.knob:before
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px; height: 12px;
  left: 44px; top: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
.knob 
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  transform: rotate(0deg);

  &:before
  {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px; height: 12px;
    left: 44px; top: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
  }
}
```

I believe it should have the same result, but as an honest CSS newbie, I don't understand what's going on. [Here's a CodePen with the full code.](https://codepen.io/mrelemental/pen/VRLrjq)

Comment: That’s [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/), not CSS.

Comment: You're don't using SCSS. You should use SCSS for this.

Comment: Ok! That explains it all haha... cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax is **SCSS** syntax. You can't write code like this in your css file. You can setup compilation from **SCSS** to **CSS**, and write your code in your **SCSS** file.